# Setting up a static template data member in an include file in a DLL

Tags: visual-studio, templates, c++-cli

I have multiple in-memory data dictionaries that I have to keep track of so I'm trying to set up an interface with the following code in an include file in a DLL:

LinkData.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <map>

#ifdef LINKDATA_EXPORTS
#define API /*__declspec(dllexport) */
#else
#define API /*__declspec(dllimport) */ 
#endif

template <typename T>
class LinkDataFactory
{
public:
    static API T Get(std::string key)
    {
        return _data[key];
    }

    template <typename T>
    static API void Set(std::string key, T value)
    {
        _data[key] = value;
    }

    private:
        API static std::map<std::string, T > _data;
};
```

The API macro is undefined because it's my understanding that the template class resides in an include file and will be instantiated at compile time.

I try to use the static class with the following code:

```
#include "LinkData.hpp"
//...
LinkDataFactory<std::string>::Set(key, data);
```

The compile fails with the error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol 
"public: static class 
std::map<
    class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>, class std::allocator<char> >,
    class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,
    struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,
    class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const ,
    class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > 
LinkDataFactory<
    class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >
```

Defining the API macros gets the error:

```
error C2491: 'LinkDataFactory<T>::Set' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
```

What's going on?  Is what I'm trying even possible?

Comment: I'm not a VS expert but are you sure  you want to `__declspec(dllimport)` the method of the templated class? The body (implementation) of the method is in the header file anyway...

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg any combination of defined or undefined API macros results in a link error.  No defined API macros results in a link error.

Comment: I'm not sure it this a problem here but labels in general in c++ should not start with underscore...

Comment: You are up to your eyeballs in Template Hell.  It is technically possible, you'll have to write a template specialization for T = std::string and export its _data definition.  The odds that this ends well are low.

Comment: Thanks, @HansPassant.  I was looking for a way  to simplify the data factory.  Looks like this way will be way more complicated that the simple stupid way of a private collection with public setters and getters for each type.  So simple stupid it is.